# How to pass a Java Class in .putExtra

Tags: java, android

Well, I've got a MainActivity which gets data from a weather API to display it on an ArrayList, I make the HTTP request and all the stuff inside a Java Class called QueryUtils, the thing is, I'm making a SecondaryActivity which extracts the info from the same API, so I don't want to make another HTTP request, so I'm wondering how to pass this QueryUtils info inside a .putExtra so I can use the same request.
If there is another way to do It without using .putExtra (I'm a noob, I'm sure there is another way) I wouldn't mind.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your QueryUtils class should implements [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html), so you can use putExtra.
With Android Studio you can use the [Parcelable plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator) that generates automatically the Parcelable boilerplate code for you.

Check out [this post](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) about the differences between Parcelable and Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You could Refactor and Move your QueryUtils outside of Activity and make it static. You can add a function, say callAPI, which takes required parameters to call API and you can return either the ArrayList or your API response to calling Activity. Then you can call your Ouery like `QueryUtils.callAPI(parameters)` from any Activity requiring this API call.